# Distributive lattices and axiom of choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice, lattice-theory

What form of the axiom of choice is equivalent (in ZF) to the statement that every distributive lattice is isomorphic to a lattice of sets?

Comment: Do you mean an arbitrary isomorphism? (Just to make sure.)

Comment: Does https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=873595 solve your question?

Comment: No.  The Birkhoff Representation theorem is a stronger statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem) the prime ideal theorem for distributive lattices is equivalent to the Boolean prime ideal theorem. (Look in the "Further prime ideal theorems" section.)

Comment: These certainly imply the statement.  But how about AC(2), the axiom of choice for 2-element sets? (Suggested to me by a well known author.)

Comment: @Fred: That makes no sense to me, honestly.

Comment: The Boolean prime ideal theorem is trivially a special case of the prime ideal theorem for distributive lattices (the reverse implication requires a bit of work). So no, the latter is not provable from just AC(2).

Comment: Also, note that by passing to quotient algebras, the Boolean PIT is equivalent to what Wikipedia calls the *weak* PIT: every nontrivial Boolean algebra has a prime ideal. The more general statement that every nontrivial distributive lattice has a prime ideal follows from the existence of an arbitrary embedding $f$ of the lattice in a $\mathcal P(X)$, as $\{a:u\notin f(a)\}$ is a prime ideal for any fixed $u\in X$. Thus, the statement that every distrib lattice is isomorphic to a lattice of sets is already equivalent to the Boolean PIT.

Comment: I mean, any fixed $u\in\bigcup_af(a)\setminus\bigcap_af(a)$.

Comment: This shows why the original answer (now checked) is correct. The axiom AC(2) is strictly weaker.  See for example the book book by Herrlich "Axiom of Choice".